# New fbconnect Api Errors?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, xcode4, fbconnect

I am using fbconnect api in my application for images uploading on facebook wall. it works for me well about 2 months ago. but Now it's not work for me, for this purpose I integerate new fbconnect api using this link.. https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk
But its give me following 4 errors.

```
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBPermissionDialog", referenced from:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBXMLHandler", referenced from:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBStreamDialog", referenced from:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you built the sources? This can be a common problem.
Go to project settings ->  build phases -> compile sources and add the following files to the list

UPDATE:

Seems like you might not have the file in your project. Download the sdk from this link:
[Download](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk)

To download from there press the "downloads" button and download as .zip

And then find the folder labelled "src"
Drag that into your project and you should be good to go!

Also make sure to import:

```
#import "FBConnect.h"
```

And conform to the correct delegates

Comment: @Rahan Kapur i did it according to your suggestion but still it give me 3 errors

Comment: thanx for helping me so for still the same problem.